# blender is crashing while rendering fluid simulation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am trying to render a fluid simulation in cycles but after 5 frames my gpu drivers get reset, and the blender window becomes white and crashes, or not responding for hours.

my specs
cpu intel i 3 7100
gpu rx 590 8 gb
ram hyper x 8 gb 2400 mhz
I tried every resolution and samples, but it happens when I use gpu. Cpu rendering is stable, i have log file but i dont know how to post it

Render settings

[image: render settings]

Preferences

[image: preference]

in the bottom of the image is the blender window became white and task manager

[image: blender tab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Command Line Rendering. It tends to be more stable and faster than normal rendering. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9IW96FisnU) with explanation on how to do it. It is easy, there isn't much to mess up there if you follow the instructions.

Shortly said, rendering in the Command prompt (CMD) is opening blender in the background, without having it actually opened. When Blender is open, it has to keep the 3d view and much more stuff loaded. But when you run it through CMD, you make it to load only the operation you need it to do.

***How to do it***

***1. Open CMD*** - In the Windows search bar simply type "Cmd", and open it. It doesnt matter if you open it as administrator or not.

***2. Locate the blender .exe file*** - The easiest way it to use the desktop shortcut, by right clicking  on it --> `Open File Location`, but can be done from Windows start menu. The copy it and go back to CMD.

***3.  Set the working directory of the prompt*** - In CMD, type `cd <blender.exe folder>`. Usually its in `Program Files --> Blender Foundation --> Blender <version>`, but it may vary.

***4. Do the magic*** - What you have to do now is to run blender.exe, but with special settings. *One thing to note, the settings are just one letter, like `-a`, followed by specification. There is a space between the setting and the specification.*

First, start by typing `blender.exe`(dont run yet). This will open blender normally when executed.

Then, add the special settings. At first, you need to specify which project will be rendered - i.e the location of the .blend file. So, to what you have written, add `-b`- this the option, specifying the location of the file. After it, add the location. So, you should have `blender.exe -b <location of .blend file>` Dont run yet.

Now, you need to specify which frame are you rendering.
For a still image, you use `-f`, followed by the frame number - `-f <number>`.
For animation, you use `-s` for the start frame, `-e` for the end frame, and then you add `-a` to tell the program that you are rendering an animation- `-s <number> -e <number> -a`

Additionally, you can specify an output location, but thats not really necessary, if you have one in the file. Use `-o` for it, followed by the output folder.

Now, you should be left with something like this:

`blender.exe -b <.blend loc.> -f <rendered frame num.>`

or

`blender.exe -b <.blend loc.> -s <start frame num.> -e <end frame num.> -a`

All you got to do now is to run this command. It shows the progress in the CMD. One really cool thing about it, is that you can actually pause it, even on one frame renders. Just click `Pause Break` button on the keyboard while the CMD window is active. To resume, click it again However, the render gets somehow slower after resuming, so i dont recommend this.

Thats all you really need to know about it, and even if it doesnt apply for that project, its really good to know it for the future.